# This error shows when making theme (syntax error, unexpected token "endif", expecting end of file)

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, themes

While I was creating a new theme in wordpress and coding to the function.php file **endif;** turn into red mark and says
(syntax error, unexpected token "endif", expecting end of file)
the code of function.php:

```
<?php
function register_nav(){
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'header' => 'Header'
        )
    );

    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'footer' => 'Footer'
        )
    );

    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            '404' => '404'
        )
    );

}

if (! function_exists('setup'));
    function setup(){
        register_nav();
        add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
        add_image_size('team', 475, 475, array('center','center'));
    }

endif;
function scripts_header(){
    wp_enqueue_style('init', get_stylesheet_uri());
}

function scripts_footer(){
    // wp_enqueue_script('init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/init.js', array('jquery'));
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'setup');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_header');
//add_action('wp_footer', 'scripts_footer')
```

Same happen in other file to
index.php file code:

```
<?php
get_header();
if (have_posts());
    while (have_posts()) :
        the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;
get_footer();
?>
```

page.php code:

```
<?php
get_header();
if (have_posts());
    while (have_posts()) :
        the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;
get_footer();
?>
```

I look for many resources tried the keyword **endwhile;** still shows an error in the code. So finally I thought let asked about the stack overflow so can anyone help me with this problem.

Comment: Typo. `if (...);` should be `if (...):` (colon, not semi colon). You're doing it correctly for you while loops. A common practice is to only use this [alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) in views and stick to the "normal" syntax (using `{}`) in pure PHP files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo. if (...); should be if (...): (colon, not semicolon). You're doing it correctly for you while loops. A common practice is to only use this alternative syntax in views and stick to the "normal" syntax (using {}) in pure PHP files.

Credit goes to– Magnus Eriksson